# Different way to refer to a 'lowercase' letter?

Tags: single-word-requests, typography

I am looking for a different word to refer to 'lowercase' or 'small' letters, but I am unable to find any such word.

- "Large letter �"; this is used by the Unicode standard for non-latin glyphs, and designates the other type "Small letter �"
- "Upper case letter �", which refers to the way pieces of movable type were stored in printshops, along with the designation "Lower case letter �" for others.
- "Capital letter �", similar to how you have a "capital city" or "capital ship"; this does not appear to have any sort of reasonable matching designation for small letters, though.
- "Initial letter �", which refers to the fact that the large letters are used at the beginning of sentences, proper nouns, and for the initial letters of the words in an abbreviation. This too does not appear to have a comparable way to designate small letters.

A possibility is that one could refer to a lowercase letter as "Common letter �", which is neatly opposite both the "Capital" and "Initial" designations, however I have not seen this used anywhere, and I wouldn't want to make up my own word if it would confuse a reader.

Does anyone know of a designation that is more directly complimentary to "capital" or "initial"?

Comment: You left out [majuscule](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majuscule) and [minuscule](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minuscule).

Comment: The fact that both *big letter* and *large letter* are quite a bit less common than *small letter* makes me think that *small letter* has generally been used as the opposite of *capital letter*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=capital+letter%2Csmall+letter%2Cbig+letter+%2B+large+letter+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccapital%20letter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmall%20letter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28big%20letter%20%2B%20large%20letter%29%3B%2Cc0). (*Little letter* is also common, but it usually seems to mean *short missive*.)

Comment: Why break from industry norm/standard? Would we have to no longer *dial* a cell phone, watch a *film*, read news from the *press*, etc, etc?

Comment: You already have somewhere around three and a half sets of synonym pairs for this (which is rather more than you'd get for most things)—what makes you think there are even more? And why would you need or even _want_ any more?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I just edited my question; what I am looking for is a name for lowercase letters that is more directly complementary to "capital" or "initial".

Comment: The complement to *initial* is *body*. *Minuscule* and *majuscule* are lettering styles, and do not necessarily correspond to *lowercase* and *uppercase*, since the entire text can be written or set in one or the other (*viz.* Carolingian minuscule). It happens to be the case that in *most* current typefaces, uppercase letters are majuscules and lowercase letters are minuscules, but it's not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We also refer to them as *minuscules*, though this is less common. Calling a letter *small*, *lower-case* or *lowercase* is clear and concise, and you should go by those.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't know that I've heard majuscules or minuscules ever used within my hearing discussing matters of typography or written language.

I tend to think *lowercase* is by far the most prominent word to describe those characters, however, if referring to a single letter, it may also be considered *uncapitalized*.

Answer (score 2):

Educated under the British system over 40 years ago, I was taught that the small letters were referred to as common letters, while the large letters were referred to as capital letters.  Common letters does not seem to be a designation used in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, “minuscule” and “majuscule” sum it up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of an <sub><sup>**UPPERCASE**</sup></sub> letter is quite simply a <sub><sup>**LOWERCASE**</sup></sub> letter.  You should discard the other terms you are attempting to brand letters with.

*Uppercase* and *lowercase* are the correct typographic terms here; there is no need for confusing matters.  In Bringhurst’s *Elements of Typographic Style*, he consistently uses the standard abbreviations *uc* and *lc* for these.

Not all letters have case, but if they do, properties like *uppercase* and *lowercase* are mutually exclusive; although a letter can be neither, it cannot be both.

An “initial capital” version of a cased letter is called its *titlecase* in Unicode, which you can for the most part ignore the existence of.  In Unicode, every cased letter is exactly one of *uppercase*, *lowercase*, or very rarely *titlecase*, and there are mapping operations to convert between those.